# JavaScript and big numbers, calculating reserve data erc20 and bep20

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, bignumber.js

I have searched all day and still no working solution.
My problem is I am working with JavaScript to get EVM blockchain data and any library I use does not work exactly.

```
// pair
// 0 = BMON
// 1 = BUSD

// transaction
const tx0 = 2755738843649989653057n; // amount0Out BMON
const tx1 = 113747760332474227520n; // amount1In BUSD

// reserve after transaction
const x = 466822693713887341798087n; // reserve0 BMON
const y = 19334468154310748213608n; // reserve1 BUSD
const k = x * y;
console.log(k)

const newX = x + tx0;
const newY = y - tx1;
const newK = newX * newY;
console.log(newK)
```

in Uniswap a price is based off the reserves. and I get data from a Swap event what and how much goes in and out.

Just for a test to see if my calculations are 100% accurate I made the above small script.

I get the reserves data after the transaction, but I need to know the price before the transaction. I subtract what's going in and add what's going out to make a new reserve. the constant of the reserve has to be always the same. my code knows the reserve after the transaction and the reserve before the transaction when I did the add/subtract but somehow the constant is never the same as it should be.

I tried bigInt, BigNumber.js, normal numbers etc. Nothing is working. and I need it to work 100% accurate.

Is there someone who can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and you will find max safe integer value. If you go out of this range, math becomes tricky and you probably won't be happy with results.

Your math must stay in the range of max safe integer to have good results.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

You may explore BigInt but it has it's own caveats just like float point numbers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Read more here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/essential-guide-javascript-newest-data-type-bigint/#the-problem

[image]

If you found it useful, please consider upvoting/accepting

Comment: Thanks for the reply, non of those really work. seems like JavaScript is the worst language to work with blockchain values. Would you know an alternative way to do the calculations? I work with Nodejs, I think Python could handle the job of calculations, but no idea how to implement that.

Comment: not sure, this is not JavaScript specific thing but more how numbers are saved in binary format. Python has same issues, not sure if there is actually a language which would not. Yet you need some clever lib which can work around these limitations or find a way to avoid such math to begin with. `big.js` sounds like something to try in JavaScript world or mpmath in Python's. But the fundamental issues are same, it's not language specific but computer science in general. e.g. some databases to "work around" saves all numbers as strings. If answers helped, please upvote & accept :)

Comment: I have tried big.js and also saving numbers as string. The thing is somehow its done the right way in EVM blockchain and I need to know how I can do it. numbers are mostly stored as uint256 in erc20 and bep20, from there I need to make calculations for price and more. and the numbers are always a bit off.

Comment: i haven't worked with such big numbers, but usually what i found is people define the accuracy requirement of the number and then each time when accuracy may be lost like in `0.1+0.2` people switch from floats to ints, drops the remaining part and converts back to float. `Math.round((0.1+0.2)*10)/10`. This enforces accuracy of 1 number post comma. Maybe this idea will help you finding out solution. Depending on math operations i may consider searching for ways to split big numbers to small, make math like `0.1+0.2` sample and then combine to final result.

Comment: Just keep in mind you may losing accuracy each time you split & combine back so each sub operation's accuracy need to me higher then final requirement in such pattern. There is all science behind this, i studied during physic studies, if interested you may find math course on this topic. Or find lib from some math people who resolved it for you and use whatever language was used to make that lib to make the calculation. You can always use combo of languages in single app, often through `cli` e.g. in nodejs - child process https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html can run python, matlab or any

Comment: If my posts helped, please upvote/accept :)

Comment: I accepted your answer, but eventually I had to change to another way in order not to depend on exact calculations